# Database Structure Direction and Have a reference ID refer to a different table depending on another column

Tags: database-design, architecture, software-design

Working on a small proof of concept project for me and my friends DnD game and not sure if my direction for how to organize the database is the best way.  The general idea is to make a collection of character sheets (all the stats for our players for those who dont play dnd) for all the different games.  The issue is we have several different types of games.  So I thought of two ways to handle the fact that the different types of character sheets will have different fields.

1. Have a single characters table that ends up having a crap ton of columns for all the different types of character. (not a fan of this method as it seems to cluttered)
2. Have a characters table that has the basic info like owner, character name, etc. but also has a game_type_id and sheet_id.  Then have different tables (which would end up being groups of tables for things like equipment,spells, etc have their own table for each game) for each game that consists of the actual character data.  So the game_type_id would be used to know which set of tables the sheet_id is referencing

Option 1 seems to unorganized the more game types get added, but then option 2 seems it will end up creating a lot of different tables as more games are added cause each sheet will have the base info table and then all the associated tables for things there are multiple of.

So my question is what would be the best approach so all the different types of game sheets can all be kept in the characters table even though they require different fields?

Comment: So you have a character sheet which essentially holds different attributes for a player depending on the game type it is associated with? And a player will have >1 character sheet (for different game types?)

Comment: Correct, so not sure if it would be better to make a singe character table that has a crap ton of fields or separate it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are saying that a character can have numerous character sheets (which correspond to the different game types) and the attributes for the character vary based on game type. Having a wide table with all attributes will cause you future pain as attributes need to be added, deleted etc so I would suggest the following structure:

```
Character
CharacterId
CharacterName
Gender
-- other fields common to all characters

GanmeType
GameTypeId
GameTypeName
--other relevant fields

GameTypeAttributes
GameTypeAttributesId
GameTypeid
AttributeName

CharacterSheet
CharacterSheetId
CharacterId
GameTypeAttributesId
AttributeValueInt
AttributeValueVARCHAR
-- column for every data type you would use
```

As an example, the following code would create a character called Arya who is associated with the game "Big War"

In the Big War game a character must have attributes Strength, stamina and charisma.

We then set Arya's values for those attributes

```
INSERT INTO Character VALUES (1,'Arya','F');
INSERT INTO GameType VALUES (1,'Big War');
INSERT INTO GameTypeAttributes VALUES (1,1,'Strength'),(2,1,'Stamina'),(3,1,'Charisma');
INSERT INTO CharacterSheet VALUES (1,1,1,10,NULL),(2,1,2,4,NULL),(3,1,3,NULL,'None whatsoever');
```

We can then add Arya to another game if we wish:

```
INSERT INTO GameType VALUES (2,'Fuzzy Duck');
INSERT INTO GameTypeAttributes VALUES (4,2,'Stomach Strength'),(5,2,'Fearlessness'),(6,2,'Bravery');
INSERT INTO CharacterSheet VALUES (4,1,4,10,NULL),(5,1,5,4,NULL),(6,1,6,NULL,'Enourmous amounts');
```

Comment: so just have a single character sheet table and have a lot of fields to encompass the different attributes of different games?

Comment: why would you do a row for each attribute with only the two columns instead of a row being a character and make a columns the different attributes, with your method the value column couldnt be different variable types, like boolean, integer, etc.  Im not that strong on database design so i could be missing something

Comment: i've updated the answer to account for the fact that data type is of importance

Comment: another edit as the previous answer wasn't fully normalised

Answer (score 0):

You should separate them, i.e. pursue solution number 2.

In the real world, you would have one sheet per player and game, so this will be consistent with that approach, with the added benefit that you now have the commonality of the player in one table, adn the specifics of each game in per-game or per-sheet tables. However, this assumes that you have a relational database.

Perhaps you would prefer a NoSQL database like MongoDB (document-oriented) or Neo4j (graph-oriented) which allows you to represent your data in a different way. It could make it easier for you to both model and maintain information. But even in this case, you would need to conceptually keep the player separate from the games.